# Apache zeppelin process died

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to run zeppelin on Ubuntu14 w/ Hadoop 1.0.3 and Spark 1.4.0.
I've finished building the source code, and all of the package successfully finished building. But when I run the daemon, it fails and says that the Zeppelin process had died.

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

It says that it can't find the logs folder and the run folder, which are definitely there.

Answer (score 4):

Joseph,

I suggest that you try to test your zeppelin package first.

```
mvn verify
```

or check if your zeppelin process is alive or not.

```
ps -aux | grep zeppelin
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running **zeppelin** by `sudo` :

```
sudo bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
ps -ef | grep "zeppelin"
kill -9 pid
sudo bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh restart
```

Comment: Any reason for answering 3 year old questions?

Comment: I faced the same issue, none of the solution works for me, so i updated the solution which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It could be an error caused by JDK version, at least that was the case for me 
try to update jdk and build it again.

Also, make sure you are building it using the correct command

```
mvn clean package -Pspark-1.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -Phadoop-2.2 -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running zeppelin from a virtual machine make sure that you have enough RAM and CPU.  I ran into your problem when I was using Virtual Box and the default settings.  When I increased the cpu's to 2 and RAM to 4096 everything worked fine.  This is because zeppelin runs spark by default and spark is very resource intensive locally and otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried the proposed answers but none worked for me. Here is what did work for me:

- Download the [binaries](http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html), then download the build requirements:

  ```
  sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk npm libfontconfig r-base-dev r-cran-evaluate
  sudo apt install maven
  ```
- Go to the Zeppelin directory and run:

  ```
  sudo bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
  ```
- Go to `localhost:8080` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right now.. so I checked environment compatibility with my cdh then I got java compatibility issue

I setup yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk then start all the services of Hadoop with spark

Then, I started zeppelin, I made the zeppelin folder on root so I used..
sudo zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start

Or

zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start

Answer (score 0):

I took Kangrok Lee's suggestion and ran `mvn verify` on my system. It prompted me that I do not have `JAVA_HOME` set and `JAVA_HOME` must point to JDK and not JRE.
Following steps fixed for me:

1. Make sure you have JDK installed on the system where you are trying to run zeppelin
2. Make sure `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to your JDK and not JRE

After above steps are ensured `zeppelin-daemon.sh start / restart` should work for you. No need to use `sudo`.